# Install Google Cloud components error from gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubectl

I am trying to install several GCP components from the [gcloud command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) and always get the same error:

```
$ gcloud components list

Your current Cloud SDK version is: 146.0.0
The latest available version is: 146.0.0

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                  Components                                                 │
├───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬───────────┤
│     Status    │                         Name                         │            ID            │    Size   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ Not Installed │ App Engine Go Extensions                             │ app-engine-go            │  47.9 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Bigtable Command Line Tool                           │ cbt                      │   3.8 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datalab Command Line Tool                      │ datalab                  │   < 1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datastore Emulator                             │ cloud-datastore-emulator │  15.4 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datastore Emulator (Legacy)                    │ gcd-emulator             │  38.1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator                               │ pubsub-emulator          │  21.0 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Google Container Registry's Docker credential helper │ docker-credential-gcr    │   3.3 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app Java Extensions                           │ app-engine-java          │ 128.3 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app Python Extensions                         │ app-engine-python        │   7.2 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ kubectl                                              │ kubectl                  │  11.5 MiB │
│ Installed     │ BigQuery Command Line Tool                           │ bq                       │   < 1 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud SDK Core Libraries                             │ core                     │   5.7 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                      │ gsutil                   │   2.8 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Default set of gcloud commands                       │ gcloud                   │           │
│ Installed     │ gcloud Alpha Commands                                │ alpha                    │   < 1 MiB │
│ Installed     │ gcloud Beta Commands                                 │ beta                     │   < 1 MiB │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Then attempting to install [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)

```
$ gcloud components install kubectl

You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is 
managed by an external package manager.  If you would like to get the 
latest version, please see our main download page at:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) The component manager is disabled for this installation
```

Any idea why is this error raised?

Comment: Got it!. You need to install gcloud command line directly with a versioned archive instead of a package manager (apt-get or yum). It seems there is no other way to install certain aditional package if you use the later.

Comment: You can also install the components (or some of them anyway) using yum, look here:    
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#yum

Comment: I did that originally, still didn't work. Why are all MY problems ALWAYS unique in the universe?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Cloud SDK component manager only works if you don't install the SDK through another package manager.  If you want to use the component manager, you can install using one of these methods:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#interactive

Additional packages are available in our deb and yum repos so all the same components are available, you just need to use your existing package manager to install them:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#yum

Comment: Installed the SDK fine via apt, but tried `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator` and got the error: `E: Unable to locate package google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator`

Comment: You say "The Cloud SDK component manager only works if you don't install the SDK through another package manager." But in my case, I never installed gcloud; it comes preinstalled on every GCP instance. So, for those of us using docker, is that preinstallation useless?

Comment: Different GCP images are managed by different people and so the preinstalled version of the Cloud SDK can vary. The debian images install the SDK using the apt-get method mentioned above and will have all those components available. Other distros manage their own SDK package and may not have all components available. If you need something that is not available, the best option is to uninstall the SDK that comes on the image, and install using one of the above methods.

Comment: Also installed via apt-get as per the instructions, also cannot install google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator (or datastore) as per Karl's notes above.

Comment: If you get `E: Unable to locate package google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator`, you need to add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu).

Comment: In case anyone is here looking at this solution to install the docker credential helper component, it's 'not yet available' in apt repo's

Answer (score 80):

To add some more context to this answer for the Ubuntu OS, these are the steps that I took when I had already installed `google-cloud-sdk` using the `apt-get` package manager

1. Remove the existing installation using

   `sudo apt-get remove google-cloud-sdk`
2. Navigate to
   https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux and follow the steps to download the correct `tar.gz` package for your system
3. Navigate to the download directory and unzip the archive using

   `tar -zxf google-cloud-sdk-*`
4. Install the SDK using

   `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`
5. Make the `gcloud` command available by either:

   - Running `source ~/.bashrc` or
   - Closing your current terminal session and opening a new one

Using this installation I was then able to update and install [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) with the following commands

```
gcloud components update
gcloud components install kubectl
```

Comment: After step 4, you'll need to restart your terminal for the changes to take effect. Otherwise, this solution solved all my problems installing Kubernetes on Ubuntu.

Comment: I needed to use `sudo gcloud components install kubectl`

Comment: When I run 4.th command (install.sh) I am getting this kind of error:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'

Comment: Wrong answer, this is EXACTLY what I did and it still gives the same damn error claiming I installed it with a 3rd party packager which I ever so clearly did not.

Answer (score 6):

In case `apt` or `apt-get` does not uninstall gcloud try with `snap remove google-cloud-sdk`.

This might be the case if you use a newer Ubuntu version (eg. LTS 18.04).

Answer (score 6):

#### My Problem

I wanted to upgrade the `gcloud` CLI version on an existing GCE instance (Ubuntu Xenial), and running `gcloud components update` resulted in this:

```
# gcloud components update
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.
Please consider using a separate installation of the Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

#### My Solution

What I found is that the SDK executables are installed in `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk` and are included on the PATH via symlinks in `/usr/bin`:

```
# ll /usr/bin | grep google-cloud
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          30 Aug 20  2018 bq -> ../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          34 Aug 20  2018 gcloud -> ../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          52 Aug 20  2018 git-credential-gcloud.sh -> ../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/git-credential-gcloud.sh*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          34 Aug 20  2018 gsutil -> ../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil*
```

Therefore, to install the latest version, I followed steps 3 and 4 from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux:

> 3. Download the archive file best suited to your operating system.

```
# curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-247.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

> 4. Extract the archive to any location on your file system; preferably, your Home folder.

```
# tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk-247.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz google-cloud-sdk
```

and then just replaced the old `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk` directory with the new one:

```
# mv /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk-ORIG
# mv google-cloud-sdk /usr/lib/
```

This allows the symlinks already on the PATH to continue to work, keeps existing auth/config in place, and appears to support upgrades via `gcloud components update` in the future:

```
# gcloud components update

All components are up to date.
```

#### Useful Troubleshooting Commands

It might be helpful to run these before and after you upgrade `gcloud`.

Where is `gcloud` on your PATH:

```
$ which gcloud
/usr/bin/gcloud
```

What version of `gcloud` are you using:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 247.0.0
bq 2.0.43
core 2019.05.17
gsutil 4.38
```

What credentials is `gcloud` using (by default):

```
$ gcloud auth list
```

What config is `gcloud` using (by default):

```
$ gcloud config list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.
Please consider using a separate installation of the Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

I was unable to install the required **kubectl gcloud component** the reasion behind that was I used snap manager to install GCloud SDK so I also need to install kubectl via snap.

> sudo snap install kubectl --classic

it works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from google support.

> This can occur when Google Cloud SDK is installed via package manager like apt-get or yum.
> If you would like to enable Google Cloud CLI compoenent manager, you can reinstall Cloud SDK using installer[1] after uninstall existing package-manager-installed Cloud SDK by following this document[2].
> However installing 'docker-credential-gcr' is not supported by Cloud SDK so please consider to use gcloud credential helper[3] or install it via curl command[4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my side.

instead of installing it through apt tried it with snap
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive

Following the same steps.

PS: dont forget to restart `exec -l $SHELL`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install **cbt** on **Linux** machine using `remote-exec` which having below code

**exampleScript.sh**

```
gcloud components update --quiet 
gcloud components install cbt --quiet
```

**Reference terraform code**

```
resource "null_resource" "remote-exec-resource" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type     = "ssh"
      user     = "username"
      private_key = "your_ssh_key"
      host     = "your_host_external_ip"
    }
    script = "exampleScript.sh"
  }
  depends_on = [YOUR_RESOURCE]
}
```

but I was getting the same error, I resolved that by doing following workaround.

Instead of calling **exampleScript.sh** in **remote-exec**, I pass the script to **google_compute_instance**

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
    metadata_startup_script = "exampleScript.sh"
}
```

Reference for installing Cloud SDK.

https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/cloud-sdk-shows-error-sdk-component-manager-is-disabled-000004810