# Unable to install google cloud datalab on conda

Tags: conda, gcloud, google-cloud-datalab

I have a conda container with the gcloud sdk and I can initialize and login to gcloud with `gcloud init` just fine. However, if I try to install datalab with `gcloud components install datalab` I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) The components management action could not be performed because the installation root of the Cloud SDK could not be located. If you previously used the Cloud SDK installer, you could re-install the the SDK and retry again.
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: How did you install the sdk? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697026/install-google-cloud-components-error-from-gcloud-command.

Comment: via `conda install -c bioconda google-cloud-sdk` https://anaconda.org/bioconda/google-cloud-sdk

Answer (score 3):

The Google Cloud SDK component manager only works if you download the SDK through a versioned package, not through a package manager.

See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#managing_cloud_sdk_components.